# Should Identity Server 4 OpenID Connect Discovery be public?

Tags: c#, identityserver4, openid-connect

Identity Server 4 exposes OpenID Connect Discovery via `.well-known/openid-configuration` url. Now I'm not fully clear why this is here or who should have access to it. The way I understand this, all this page does is gives out information about the endpoints.

The applications that will have access to my IS4 server will have the endpoints pre-configured as they are all internal so I see no reason to have this page exposed, I see it more secure not to give out this information out.

As such, My question is should I restrict access to this page and if so how? And if not, why?

Comment: "as they are all internal", you mean that the entire application is not accessible from the internet, only within your computer/network?

Comment: No I mean the applications are internally developed and I can specify those endpoints on each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main benefit for keeping that endpoint is automatic client configuration. From the [MVC sample on the AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples GitHub page](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples/blob/62184bcf9ad0a785cd43cbec1faf059628c1ccbe/samples/Mvc/Mvc.Client/Startup.cs#L53-L56):

```
// Note: setting the Authority allows the OIDC client middleware to automatically
// retrieve the identity provider's configuration and spare you from setting
// the different endpoints URIs or the token validation parameters explicitly.
Authority = "http://localhost:54540/"
```

The server library has the ability to change any of the endpoint paths during startup, like [the endpoint for obtaining a token](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples/blob/master/samples/Mvc/Mvc.Server/Startup.cs#L98). By using automatic configuration, your applications can automatically pick up on that change without you needing to update all your client applications manually.

This functionality is only offered as a convenience, should you want to use it.

---

If this application is only exposed to your internal network (or just within your own computer or Docker network), there is absolutely no harm in leaving this be.

If this application is exposed to the public network, then you need to start asking yourself if you want an attacker to know the information that the configuration endpoint provides.

All an attacker would know is the application is an Auth server, the paths to your various endpoints, what types of OAuth2 flows you support, and maybe a few other small details. If you have publicly facing documentation, this would just be a machine-readable version of that.

Rather than focusing on preventing access to the configuration endpoint, make sure that your Auth server endpoints are authenticated. You should be checking that the Client Id and Client Secret are present and correct before giving out tokens.

From [oauth.com](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/token-introspection-endpoint/) (this is about the introspection endpoint but really the principle applies to all endpoints):

> If the introspection endpoint is left open and un-throttled, it presents a means for an attacker to poll the endpoint fishing for a valid token. To prevent this, the server must either require authentication of the clients using the endpoint, or only make the endpoint available to internal servers through other means such as a firewall.